# What is the difference between quotation marks and the colon in chef attributes?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefdk

I am currently creating a wrapper cookbook, while trying to restrict myself to the correct formatting by using Rubocop and Foodcritic. However, I constantly get the following errors:

```
Use strings in preference to symbols to access node attributes
```

and

```
Access node attributes in a consistent manner
```

this made me wonder, Is there a difference between colons and quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...colons are used for defining symbols while strings are defined by quotes... so:

`:variable1` is a symbol named variable1

`:'variable is 1'` is a symbol

`'variable1'`  - is a string

`"variable#{1}"`  - is a string that could have variables defined in it. Double quotes interpret the string while single quotes use the string as is.

and

'variable1'.to_sym is same as :variable1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Sid's answer, `:foo` is a symbol while `"foo"` and `'foo'` are strings. For node attributes we automatically convert things for you so both styles will work. The Foodcritic rules are there to ensure a consistent style in all your Chef code. If you don't have a reason to do otherwise, we recommend the string style as quoted strings are common in many programming languages and so are more likely to be understood by less Ruby-fluent readers.